# JPA/SQL - Filter table with a composite primary key and perform join on it in 1 query

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables that I need to use to get relevant entries based on a few conditions.

Table A (with *id* being a primary key) is as follows

```
id  | name  | age  | status
id1 | name1 | age1 |   n
id2 | name2 | age2 |   n
id3 | name3 | age3 |   n
id4 | name4 | age4 |   n
```

Table B (with *id* & *country* being a composite primary key & *id* being a common column in 2 tables) is as follows

```
id  | country
id1 | country1
id1 | country2
id2 | country1
id3 | country2
id4 | country1
```

Now I would like to use a join on these 2 tables to get entries from table A on a condition that entries in table B have country1 but not country2. In other words, from data in 2 tables provided the desired output will be

```
id  | name  | age  | status
id2 | name2 | age2 |   n
id4 | name4 | age4 |   n
```

So here id1 is not part of the output since table B has entries with country1 & country2 for id1.

I am using spring data JPA and @Query to perform my queries (on postgres db).

My initial idea was just to chain multiple AND statements like so

```
select entryA
from tableA entryA
  left join tableB entryB on entryA.id = entryB.id
where entryB.country <> 'country1'
  and entryB.country = 'country2'
```

However, that didn't work (I still see id1 entry as my final output).

I also tried to use CASE IF END as below

```
select entryA
from tableA entryA
  left join tableB entryB on entryA.id = entryB.id
where case if entryB.country <> 'country1' then true
           else false
      end
  and entryB.country = 'country2'
```

But that doesn't work since CASE END is not suppose to come after WHERE (judging from exception I am getting). I tried to move it around, placing in different places within my query but I never managed to make it work.

I also tried to use COUNT in my query within CASE END arg but again couldn't figure out how to organise the query.

The biggest problem I have is I don't know how to put different pieces of the query together in 1 query. I feel like with COUNT, CASE END and left join it is doable. I just cannot put it all together it seems.

So the question I have: well, first of all is what I want to achieve possible to do in 1 query (if not with JPA, then is it possible with native query)? If it is, what am I doing wrong and what is the correct query for this?

Comment: Remove the `if` to get valid case expression syntax. However, I'd skip the case anyway and use regular AND/OR instead,

Comment: Can you check whether below answer give you the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select entryA.id as id, (array_agg(entryA.name))[1] as name, (array_agg(entryA.age))[1] as age, (array_agg(entryA.status))[1] as status
from tableA entryA
inner join tableB entryB on entryA.id = entryB.id
group by entryA.id having 'country1'= any(array_agg(entryB.country)) 
and array_length(array_agg(entryB.country),1) = 1
```

You can use above query for your task.

Comment: Hello! Sorry was trying to make it work and resolve my issues. Currently stuck on resolving the error below:

 ```ERROR: column "entryA.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function```

Comment: I used array_agg to capture grouped data as array

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go with array_agg in about an hour when I come back (previous suggestions were sadly ineffective). Thanks for the suggestions never the less thou! Also, is there a way to make it so I don't have to repeat entry. part? It is not a big deal but would be nice.

Comment: It worked. I still want to simplify it but will accept the answer.Ta!